# remove pipe chars in latex doc

Tags: tables, macros, symbols, catcodes, longtabu

My Doxygen project generate latex files. I can have a custom LaTeX header, but beyond that I don't have much control over the LaTeX content generated by Doxygen.

Unfortunately the table formatting in the current Doxygen version is fixed, and looks like this:

```
\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt [c]{*3{|X[-1]}|}
```

At best, I'd like to transform it into:

```
\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt [l]{*3{X[-1]}}
```

(`c` -> `l` and `|` removed)

The most important would be to remove ("nullify") the `|`, since I don't want vertical bars to appear in my tables.

I've read somewhere about the `\catcode` command but no matter what I try (like adding `\catcode`\|=12`in my LaTeX header), the`|` are still considered during the tables formatting.

Any way to hack this?

As a bonus, any way to replace `[c]` by `[l]` (without being able to actually modify the LaTeX content itself, just the header)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post-process the LaTeX files in your workflow? Then you could write a simple sed/awk script. That would be the simplest way, I think. Hacking the longtabu environment will give you much more headache, I suppose.

Comment: You could use `\arrayrulewidth0pt` to get rid of the lines, but this would also affect \hline. Beside this there imho no simple solution, you would have to patch the tabu code.  To change [c] to [l] you will imho have to patch `\LT@array`.